# TS2339: Property 'whyDidYouRender' does not exist on type 'FC<ButtonProps>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Maybe a stupid question, but why this error TS2339?!

```
import * as React from 'react';

import StyledButton from './Button.styled';

interface ButtonProps {
    label?: String;
    onClick?: (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => any | Function;
    whyDidYouRender?: any;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = (props: ButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <StyledButton onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.label}
        </StyledButton>
    )
};
Button.whyDidYouRender = true;

export default Button;
```

Error on this line: `Button.whyDidYouRender = true;`

And how I can fix this??

Comment: What is the other part of the error?

Comment: I have only this one: `TS2339: Property 'whyDidYouRender' does not exist on type 'FC<ButtonProps>'.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Edit:

Now that I understand your use case, here's a simpler answer. Change the line where you do the assignment to

```
(Button as any).whyDidYouRender = true
```

That will let you set the property once and otherwise treat it as a regular functional component.

#### Original Answer:

You're trying to treat the function Button as if it had the type `Button: ButtonProps`, but Button is declared as `Button: React.FC<ButtonProps>`.

`FC<ButtonProps>` is short for

```
(props: ButtonProps) => React.Node
// (this is slightly simplified)
```

which means it's a function that takes in a props object of type `ButtonProps` and returns a React node (roughly, a  representation of an html element like a button).

So, inside the body of the function, you can access `props.label` and `props.onClick`, which you do. You could also access `props.whyDidYouRender` inside the function body.

The mistake you're making is that those properties exist on the argument `props`, not on the `Button` function.

```
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = (props: ButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <StyledButton onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.label}
            // You can do this, because props: ButtonProps
            {props.whyDidYouRender}
        </StyledButton>
    )
};
// FC<ButtonProps> doesn't have a whyDidYouRender property, so this fails.
Button.whyDidYouRender = true;
```

If you want to access `whyDidYouRender` inside the function, you should pass it in as a prop.

If you really want the assignment `Button.whyDidYouRender = true` to succeed, you could change the type of `Button`.

```
Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> & {whyDidYouRender: any} = (props) => ...
```

That's probably not what you actually want to do, but it's not clear from the example what you are trying to accomplish, so that's the best I can do.

Comment: I followed the documentation and just added one property, but got an error: https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render, `Usage` section...

Answer (score 5):

Adding a reference to `react-app-env.d.ts` like this solved the problem:

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
/// <reference types="@welldone-software/why-did-you-render" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well. You could use the definition of Function Component in the typings for why-did-you-render (https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render/commit/1dadd54860bd5a718520142285700a0f9b4fe901) instead of React's own definition of FC.

Then, you'd have to `import React from '@welldone-software/why-did-you-render'` and use `React.FC`. Consider aliasing it (`import React as WhyDidYouRenderReact from '@welldone-software/why-did-you-render'` and use `WhyDidYouRenderReact.FunctionComponent`), such that you can still import React from 'react' if you run into trouble with that not being imported.

Alternatively, you could define it yourself and extend the existing definition of FunctionComponenet (FC is just an alias for FunctionComponent) as proposed by Tristan. That would be more correct as you'd preserve the original types of FunctionComponent.

Here's an example of how to do that in a separate module if you'd like to avoid decorating all the component you have that need this property with `& { whyDidYouRender?: boolean }` as you'd need to do if you follow Tristans solution:

```
declare module 'augmented-react' {
  import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
  export type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P> & {
    whyDidYouRender?: boolean
  };
}
```

Then, you'd have to import FC from augmented-react instead of React.

Comment: Can you please provide some example of how to do this?

Comment: declare module 'augmented-react' {
  import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
  export type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P> & {
    whyDidYouRender?: boolean;
  };
}

Answer (score -4):

It is a typescript error... `whyDidYouRender` is not defined on the FC type.

Comment: But how I can fix it??!

Comment: Define a new type and use that as the type for your Button instead.